# Как сделать слайдер картинок на jquery?

Tags: jquery

инфы много в инете, но они все с использование готовых плагинов. хотелось бы научиться с нуля...

Answer (score 3):

Тут все как раз и зависит от того, какой слайдер. Как в нем менять картинки, бекграундом ставить их или нет (чтобы было труднее спереть или текст сверху писать, не морочаясь с блоками и абсолютными позициями). Так что берете парочку разных готовых, разбираетесь в них и спокойненько делаете такой, какой нужен именно вам.

Comment: мне как на сайте megafonkavkaz.ru

Comment: такие есть готовые, обычно их сразу "оптом" выкладывают с разными "мордочками" и функционалом

Comment: Я в курсе, что есть готовые.. мне бы пошаговую инструкцию

Comment: дык в чем проблема то сделать такого же рода? разбираем его по костям. смотрим что к чему и как привязано. затем делаем скрипт на пхп для цифорок (не рисовать же их руками в редакторах.) далее скрипт для создания превьюшек. потом скрипт выдачи этого всего в правильной форме и наконец пишем слайдер на квере (можно и у них взять и разобрать по костям)

Answer (score 2):

Велосипед? Напишете один в один, как в готовых скриптах, ничего нового не изобретете. А переделать готовое проще, чем писать с нуля. Но можете в принципе написать и сами. Сделайте список картинок, оберните их в div и там уже играйтесь с параметрами видимости и движения элементов.

Comment: я не хочу изобретать ничего нового, просто чисто для себя хочу научиться этому...

Comment: Тогда читай про cfm JQuery. <br />
http://jquery-docs.ru/
<br />
Тебе нужно научиться перемещать на определенный шаг список. <br />
Просто посмотри как сделаны готовые, и по их примеру напиши.

Comment: cfm??? что это?

Comment: *сам JQuery